# Converting JGD2011 coordinates - Japan

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, google-earth, japan

I have coordinates for an area in Japan, where the survey has used the coordinates -8073.896, 63828.792. I'm not sure what coordinate system this is however I'm trying to convert this using online software to correct for JGD2011 however this plots points with a ~30km offset from where they should be.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or convert the coordinates so that they can be used in Google Earth?

Comment: Do you know in which prefecture is it located?

Comment: Its in system 10, in the Aomori Prefecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used QGIS to set the coordinates based on the information you gave us. I did the following:

1. I created a CSV File with the following information:

   ID,X,Y

   1,-8073.896, 63828.792
2. I loaded the CSV into QGIS. When the point appear in QGIS, the CRS
   is WGS84 by default, which is not correct.
3. Right-click the point and go to `Set Layer CRS` and choose `JGD2011 / Japan Plane Rectangular CS X, then save layer as to a new shapefile with the new coordinate system to become permanent.
4. Load the new saved Shapefile from Step 3, and save it again with a new shapefile of CRS WGS84.
5. Open the shapefile created from Step 4 in Google Earth, and the output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I suggest to start off in QGIS with `Settings -> Options -> CRS`, `CRS for new Layers` should be set to `Prompt for CRS`. That avoids any kind of wrong default CRS assignment.